# Oracle xmltable ORA-19224: XPTY0004 - XQuery static type mismatch: expected - node()* got - xs:string

Tags: oracle

I have a table with XML data. Cannot use real names.

```
<properties>
<property>
    <string>KEY1</string>
    <string>A</string>
</property>
<property>
    <string>KEY2</string>
    <string>B</string>
</property>
<property>
    <string>KEY3</string>
    <string>C</string>
</property>
<property>
    <string>KEY4</string>
    <string>D</string>
</property><properties>
```

Table - TESTDATA
Column - DATA

I am trying the following sql:

```
select xt.*
from TESTDATA,
xmltable('/properties/property'
passing DATA
columns KEY varchar2(100) PATH 'string[1]',
VALUE varchar2(100) PATH 'string[2]'
) xt
;
```

I am getting the following error:

ORA-19224: XPTY0004 - XQuery static type mismatch: expected - node()* got - xs:string 
19224. 00000 -  "XPTY0004 - XQuery static type mismatch: expected - %s got - %s "
*Cause:    The expression could not be used because it's static type is not appropriate for the context in which it was used.
*Action:   Fix the expression to be of the required type or add appropriate cast functions around the expression.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. The column was a CLOB. I needed to convert it to XMLTYPE - XMLTYPE(DATA) in the SQL.

thanks